Consulta sql, php
estoy intentando de hacer dos consultas pero no logro hacerlo, lo que quiero hacer es que me muestre el total de resultados que contengan el mismo valor ejemplo, estoy mostrando una serie de categorias de articulos y dentro de esas categorias quiero que me muestre informacion y el total de registros de otra consulta distinta este es mi codigo:
<!-- Aqui empieza la consulta de categorias o tags -->
<?php 
$tags = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY id ASC");
while ($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tags)){ 
?>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="card card-item">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tags pb-1">
          <a href="#" class="tag-link tag-link-md tag-link-blue">
             <?php echo $tag['name'];?>
          </a>
      </div>
      <p class="card-text fs-14 truncate-4 lh-24 text-black-50">
        <?php echo $tag['description'];?>
     </p>
     <div class="d-flex tags-info fs-14 pt-3 border-top border-top-gray mt-3">
       <p class="pe-1 lh-18">
       <!-- Aqui la segunda consulta la cual mostrara datos segun el id de la primer 
       consulta (por ello $tag['id'] -->
       <?php if ($result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE tag1 LIKE 
       '%'".$tag['id']."'%' OR tag2 LIKE '%'".$tag['id']."'%' OR tag3 LIKE 
       '%'".$tag['id']."'%' OR tag4 LIKE '%'".$tag['id']."'%' ORDER BY id")) { $row_cnt 
       = mysqli_num_rows($result); printf($row_cnt); mysqli_free_result($result); } ?> 
       pregunta(s) referente(s).</p>
                       </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>

ya intente miles de maneras posibles y no logro hacer que funcione, ayudaaa porfavor amigos.

Te has planteado hacer una única consulta con un join entre la tabla questions y la tabla tags, de manera que ya te vengan los valores que coinciden? Por otra parte estás mezclando procesos con presentación, es muy recomendable que separes las consultas y datos del html, eso te va a complicar mucho entender lo que hace tu codigo

Como bien dice @Jakala en su comentario, asumiendo que la realidad de tus datos es algo parecido a esto, podemos pensar en una solución más efectiva ejecutando esta única consulta:
SELECT 
  `t`.`id`, 
  `t`.`name`, 
  `t`.`description`,
  COUNT(*) AS `related` 
FROM `tags` AS `t` 
  LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q1` ON `q1`.`tag1`=`t`.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q2` ON `q2`.`tag2`=`t`.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q3` ON `q3`.`tag3`=`t`.`id` 
  LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q4` ON `q4`.`tag4`=`t`.`id` 
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
ORDER BY `t`.`id` ASC;

La cual arrojará un resultado como este:



id
name
description
related




1
Tag 1
Descripción Tag 1
3


2
Tag 2
Descripción Tag 2
3


3
Tag 3
Descripción Tag 3
2


4
Tag 4
Descripción Tag 4
2



Aplicándolo a tu código tendríamos esto:
<?php 
    $tags = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT 
      `t`.`id`, 
      `t`.`name`, 
      `t`.`description`,
      COUNT(*) AS `related` 
    FROM `tags` AS `t` 
      LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q1` ON `q1`.`tag1`=`t`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q2` ON `q2`.`tag2`=`t`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q3` ON `q3`.`tag3`=`t`.`id` 
      LEFT JOIN `questions` AS `q4` ON `q4`.`tag4`=`t`.`id` 
    GROUP BY `t`.`id` 
    ORDER BY `t`.`id` ASC");
    $div='
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card card-item">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="tags pb-1">
                    <a href="#" class="tag-link tag-link-md tag-link-blue">%s</a>
                </div>
                <p class="card-text fs-14 truncate-4 lh-24 text-black-50">%s</p>
                <div class="d-flex tags-info fs-14 pt-3 border-top border-top-gray mt-3">
                    <p class="pe-1 lh-18">Preguntas frecuentes: %s</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

    while ($tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tags))
    {
        printf($div,$tag['name'],$tag['description'],$tag['related']);
    }
?>

Para mayor claridad en el código, toda la parte HTML la he metido en una variable $div, poniendo marcadores %s donde irían los valores, luego, con printf, dentro del while, sustituimos los marcadores por los valores reales. Con esto damos al código un enfoque moderno, parecido a lo que hacen las plantillas por ejemplo.
Espero te sea de utilidad. Cualquier duda, pregunta en comentarios.

estoy probando el codigo pero no me funciona, se queda la pagina en blanco :(

Para verificar si trae datos prueba a poner var_dump($tag); dentro del bloque while.
